# How do you make a cursor loop a JFrame to keep it in focus?

Tags: java, jframe, cursor, focus

So I am making a 3D game in Java with no engine, and the only problem I've encountered is that if I move the cursor too much to one side, it will become visible again (as I make it invisible when focused) and lose focus. Is there some method I can implement that would loop the cursor back to the other end of the screen, instead of going off the screen? An example would be an 800x600 window of Minecraft open and you move the cursor all the way to one side, but it still stays focused on the game.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `Robot.moveMouse(...)` method to move the mouse cursor. I guess you would do this when you loseFocus.